# Is it possible for CloudFlare to cause an increase in bandwidth usage?

Tags: bandwidth

We started using CloudFlare at the end of May 2011 and I was just looking at the numbers and saw our usage of bandwidth went from 2-3k GB per month to 18k+ GB of use per month. Also our Unique vistors dropped from 60-80k to 800ish.

Could CloudFlare be causing these numbers to change so drastically? We host podcasts ourselves and I am wondering if CloudFlare is trying to cache them multiple times causing all this bandwidth usage or something.

Usage:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When it starts to cash your site it will use lots of bandwidth at a short time. but after a while it saves you a lot, so answer is NO.

if your site has lot's of visitors when it points to Cloadflare nameservers it uses lot's of bandwidth to download all requested static content to Cloadflare CDNs from your site. so it might be down for a while at first. but when caching is completed it boost's speed and saves bandwidth.

Comment: you can use cloadFlare's Google analystic widget to be sure you get right analystic report.

Comment: Define "short time." The question specifically says Alan started using them in May. It seems reasonable that any caching backlog should already be long done with.